How to display 3D map in RealityKit?
Is there existing library or 3rd party tools that can render something like this in RealityKit, given an arbitrary coordinate?

I tried adding MapKit with .realistic elevations in RealityView, but it's rendered as a flat surface.
Map(
    initialPosition: .camera(
      MapCamera(centerCoordinate: someCoordinate, distance: 2000, heading: 0, pitch: 45))
)
.mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))



In visionOS 1.1, Apple MapKit's (like any other map-generating framework) maps can't be rendered as real 3D objects (even when Realistic Elevation is turned on). The maps can show pseudo 3D elevation only on a flat 2D layer, the same way as SceneKit's 3D scene is rendered as 2D view in visionOS.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import MapKit

@main struct YourApp : App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .windowStyle(.volumetric)
        .defaultSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.5, depth: 0.5, in: .meters)
    }
}


struct ContentView : View {
    let map = Map(initialPosition:
            .camera(MapCamera(centerCoordinate: .init(latitude: 38.897957, 
                                                     longitude: -77.036560), 
                                      distance: 2000, heading: 0, pitch: 45))
    )
    var body: some View {
        map
            .mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))
            .mask(Circle())
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(90), axis: .x)
            .frame(depth: 900, alignment: .center)
        
        RealityView { content in
            let cylinder = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateCylinder(height: 0.05, 
                                                               radius: 0.14))
            cylinder.position += [0.0, 0.22, 0.08]
            content.add(cylinder)
        }
    }
}


Here is only one solution: create 3D elevation objects yourself.

I think that no one except Apple (considering their resources) is capable of creating maps with 3D elevation for RealityKit. Competitors like Google and Yandex are definitely not interested in this.

I put in a Feedback Assistant request for volumetric MapKit views, I'd encourage others to do the same.

Potentially, instead of using RealityKit primitives for each building on the 3D map, Apple could use a second image layer for the Geometry Modifier.

Personally I'm more interested in the terrain which is definitely a 3D mesh. Please file MapKit Vision requests, the more they get the more likely they will implement it.

How can we control the height of the map in the volume space? transforms don't seem to work.

Mapbox supports visionOS beginning with their version 11.2.0-beta.1 of Mapbox Maps. Find a screenshot and a quick note about limitations at https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/11.2.0-beta.1/documentation/mapboxmaps/work-with-visionos/. I haven't tried this SDK yet.
Glacier Peak Studios has published a visionOS version of Topo Maps+, which looks quite nice in the 3D mode. Based on tracing with Proxyman, I believe they're using Mapbox. You're still limited to a 2D map draped over a 3D surface, with no building extrusions. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/topo-maps/id672246353
Here are Topo Maps+ renders of Yosemite National Park:


